# Customizing menu shortcuts in Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, localization

I have several item in the context menu with the same shortcut character.

How can I disable the shortcut for those items that I rarely use?

In my case, the shortcut is "G_r_afik anzeigen" (probably "View image" in the English version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some peeking, I found that all the UI is in the file `omni.jar`. To change the shortcut, you need to edit the `accesskey` of the label defined in `chrome/de/locale/browser/browser.dtd`. In my case, the patch looks like so:

```
diff -r 4a8bdaa9a867 chrome/browser/content/browser/browser.xul
--- a/chrome/browser/content/browser/browser.xul        Mon Apr 25 17:56:36 2011 +0200
+++ b/chrome/browser/content/browser/browser.xul        Tue Apr 26 22:31:21 2011 +0200
@@ -609,7 +609,6 @@
        oncommand="gContextMenu.reloadImage();"/>
  <menuitem id="context-viewimage"
        label="&viewImageCmd.label;"
-                accesskey="&viewImageCmd.accesskey;"
        oncommand="gContextMenu.viewMedia(event);"
        onclick="checkForMiddleClick(this, event);"/>
  <menuitem id="context-viewvideo"
diff -r 4a8bdaa9a867 chrome/browser/content/browser/web-panels.xul
--- a/chrome/browser/content/browser/web-panels.xul     Mon Apr 25 17:56:36 2011 +0200
+++ b/chrome/browser/content/browser/web-panels.xul     Tue Apr 26 22:31:21 2011 +0200
@@ -130,7 +130,6 @@
        oncommand="gContextMenu.reloadImage();"/>
  <menuitem id="context-viewimage"
        label="&viewImageCmd.label;"
-                accesskey="&viewImageCmd.accesskey;"
        oncommand="gContextMenu.viewMedia(event);"
        onclick="checkForMiddleClick(this, event);"/>
  <menuitem id="context-viewvideo"
diff -r 4a8bdaa9a867 chrome/de/locale/browser/browser.dtd
--- a/chrome/de/locale/browser/browser.dtd      Mon Apr 25 17:56:36 2011 +0200
+++ b/chrome/de/locale/browser/browser.dtd      Tue Apr 26 22:31:21 2011 +0200
@@ -347,7 +347,6 @@
<!ENTITY reloadImageCmd.label         "Grafik neu laden">
<!ENTITY reloadImageCmd.accesskey     "G">
<!ENTITY viewImageCmd.label           "Grafik anzeigen">
-<!ENTITY viewImageCmd.accesskey       "r">
<!ENTITY viewImageInfoCmd.label       "Grafik-Info anzeigen">
<!ENTITY viewImageInfoCmd.accesskey   "o">
<!ENTITY viewVideoCmd.label           "Video anzeigen">
```

Change the file, create a new JAR, **backup the old omni.jar**, stop firefox, copy the new file into the old one's place, start firefox from a console[*], pray.

[*] That allows you to see if you made any errors editing the files.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [ffchrome](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/ffchrome/):

> a nifty little addon that slims and trims your context menus on the fly for simplicity, ease of use, easy access and eliminates the clutter.
>
> Menus show only the essential items by
>   default. You can hover the mouse on
>   "Show All" and menus expand on the
>   fly. You can change the timing from
>   the options box.

Comment: I tried it; at first glance it seems better than "menu editor" but while I could find the entry that I wanted to remove, I couldn't find the entry that I wanted to see. The list contains roughly 1000 elements and there is no search :-( So while it might work, it's too  hard to use for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [menu editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/menu-editor/) which will allow you, at the very least, to remove those menu entries you do not want (since they clash in shortcut with another entry).
Not a perfect solution, but should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't allow me to edit the menu; I can only delete it completely. Not really useful since I'd like to keep the option.