# Firefox keyboard shortcuts to menu items / add-on functions

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, browser-addons, context-menu

*At the moment I'm using context menus a lot to access commands in Firefox, but I would like to replace this repetitive clicking and searching with keyboard shortcuts for the common tasks that I perform.*

#### How to assign keys to add-on functionality?

E.g. I use `Close Other Tabs` from `Tab Mix Plus` a lot - but I could not find any add-on that allows me to create a key combination for it e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd>?

- My search did yield [Key config](http://keyconfig.petricek.net/), but this extension does not allow mapping to add-on functions
- I thought [Menu Editor](http://menueditor.mozdev.org/) might be relevant, as you can change menus with it, and re-arrange even add-on items
- A rather demanding solution here, which seems to require re-compiling some jar files [Customizing menu shortcuts in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/275197/customizing-menu-shortcuts-in-firefox)

Comment: You can use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to do such things for just about any Windows application. Dunno what OS you're using though...

Comment: @martineau Im using Windows, but can AutoHotKey be used to create shortcuts for functions within Firefox ?? And furthermore shortcuts to Firefox add-on functions?

Comment: AutoHotKey can substitute and/or send keystrokes and mouse events to just about anything running on your PC -- in general it doesn't care what the application is (although it can be made to if desired).