# What is the keyboard shortcut in Firefox for the forward/backward button right click tab history?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, history

I have no mouse enabled and find it rather difficult to find a really comprehensive list of shortcuts for firefox. I imagine there might be some way to have every user interface command mapped onto a shortcut. But where can I find information about it?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Firefox keyboard shortcuts to menu items / add-on functions](http://superuser.com/questions/446073/firefox-keyboard-shortcuts-to-menu-items-add-on-functions)

Comment: Forward/backward is just alt + arrowkeys, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

> Keyboard shortcuts - Perform common Firefox tasks quickly

This is a list of keyboard shortcuts in Mozilla Firefox:
http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly

For example, Ctrl + Shift + H opens the library windows (History)

Comment: thank you but this is was the first resource I looked up anyway. There is no kbsc listed for the right click tab history on the back button...I suspect firefox is not designed with only keyboard in mind but somewhere in my mind I hope there is  a way to do anything with the keyboard.

Comment: Unfortunately I could't find any other information about the keyboard shortcuts in Firefox :(